# What does "The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid." mean?

Tags: c#

I have a c# program that runs every night and it connects to a remote server using a `sftp` connection to read files.

```
 //get first level directory
 string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(remoteDir, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

 foreach (string d in dirs)
 {
     //if it doesn't contain cache or placeholder then continue
     if (!d.Contains("cache") && !d.Contains("placeholder"))
     {
         //get second level directory
         string[] SecondLeveldirs = Directory.GetDirectories(d + "\\", "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

         foreach (string sl in SecondLeveldirs)
         {
             //get files
             string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(sl + "\\");

             foreach (string f in fileEntries)
             {
                    string file = f.Substring(f.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                    string loc = sl.Replace("\\", "/").Replace("/html", "") + "/" + file;

                    conP8.Open();
                    sql = "sql inserting file and loc";
                    cmdP8 = new iDB2Command(sql, conP8);
                    cmdP8.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conP8.Close();
             }

         }

     }
 }
```

The code works great and does what it needs to but around half way through the code it gets the error.

> The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid.

I have googled the error and haven't found anything that seems useful for me, it all looks like other programs that are getting this error. I think it might be some files are getting changed while it is going through and reading all of them but I don't know yet. Does anyone have an idea on what this means?

Stack Trace:

> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path) at WebImageP.Program.PopulateWEBIMAGEP() at WebImageP.Program.Main(String[] args)

Comment: Which method causes this error? Could you please share the stack trace

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I added the stack trace

Comment: During the transfer, something on the server is renaming, moving, or deleting that file.

Comment: Sometimes the error isn't very helpful and actually masks the real issue. Not sure if this is the case here or not. But when you say `around half way through` this makes me think there might be some memory leak issue. I assume there is a database conneciton at some point. Make sure you are always closing your connections.  Also, if you are reading the content of the files, make sure you are properly disposing of your streams and readers. I could be off base here, but it's a place to start.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston I actually only had a little code not showing so I added it in. I am closing the connection to the p8 which is where I am saving the info.

Comment: Ok, so you are not reading the content of the file? `f` is just the file name?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston yes just the filename. all we need is to save the filename.

Comment: It fails on Windows error 1006, ERROR_FILE_INVALID.  When you use SFTP then such error codes tend to get unreliable, google "sftp error 1006 server disconnected" for a better explanation.  Such a mishap is of course not unusual at all.

Comment: Ok, someone else made a comment that looks like he deleted, but I think he made a good point. Can you get access to the server logs?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston our server has nothing usefull and we are trying to find out if the other server has any logs or if they are doing something at that time that would stop us from reading files